# Video only working on pc, not tablet or phone?

Tags: php, html, video, mobile

I've made this webpage, but the video on the frontpage only works on pc? If I open it on my phone or tablet, I either get nothing or a black square?
Anyone have any ideas?

http://lind.presssoft.dk/

Comment: This question is unlikely to be answered because you have not included enough detail. What is the file format for example?

Comment: It has been answered and it is now working

Comment: well now I look silly.

Comment: where is your code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that autoplay function aren't supported on IOS or Android.

Comment: Hm... What can I use then? Is it not possible to get it to autoplay then?

Comment: https://www.aerserv.com/why-does-video-autoplay-on-mobile-devices-not-work/

Comment: Yes, I just read up on it. Can you give me a hint on how to put a play button in to it?

Comment: Nevermind I got it! I put in controls here: <video controls autoplay